# Stack Exchange App: Facebook Login Error

Tags: support, android-app, login, facebook

I've just downloaded the app from the Google Play store, I can't login with Facebook. If I click on the button it shows me the following error:

> Unable to login with Facebook:response from facebook had no email

I can't do anything, I can't insert email neither password.

[image: Login failed with Facebook account]

Comment: Do you have problems logging in with FB on other apps? Do you have your email address filled in on your FB profile?

Comment: No I don't have problems on other apps... Only here, and I still can't log-in